# how to fix the styling of component

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to set the position of this component in the body, the issue is when I minimize the page , it changes as in the right picture.
I hope my question is clear.

[image: issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use % instead of px while u set the width,height,padding,etc of the element

Comment: Please share the code snippet..For the component style..Looks like issue with Margin left on component